# How to insert vertical line in the middle of page and move form to the left (css)

Tags: css

I have a quick question. How can I move my login form div to the left and have a vertical separator in the center of the page and still be able to place content on the right side of the page as well? What I thought of doing is using display: inline but when I use display: inline in my wrapper div it ruins the setup of the page. Thanks!

Code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

body {
  background-color: #ced4da;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.login-form {
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.email-input-field,
.password-input-field,
.submit-button {
  display: block;
}

input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 250px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: grey;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #3DBB96;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="login-form">
      <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
        <div class="email-input-field">
          <input type="email" name="emailPost" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="password-input-field">
          <input type="password" name="passwordPost" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="splitter"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively simple using Flexbox, we don't set a flex value on the `div.leftside` so it's width stays dependent on the content, the `splitter` can be represented by a border,  however having it being a separate element opens more styling possibilities

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #1d1f20;
  color: #FFF;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.rightSide {
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #7e7eff;
}

.leftSide {
  background: #262658;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.splitter {
  background: grey;
  width: 10px;
}

.login-form {
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.email-input-field,
.password-input-field,
.submit-button {
  display: block;
}

input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 250px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: grey;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #3DBB96;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="leftSide">
    <div class="login-form">
      <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
        <div class="email-input-field">
          <input type="email" name="emailPost" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="password-input-field">
          <input type="password" name="passwordPost" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="splitter"></div>
  <div class="rightSide">


  </div>
</div>
```

---

Same can be achieved using CSS Grid

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #1d1f20;
  color: #FFF;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
}

.rightSide {
  background: #7e7eff;
}

.leftSide {
  background: #262658;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.splitter {
  background: grey;
  width: 10px;
}

.login-form {
  background-color: #1d1f20;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.email-input-field,
.password-input-field,
.submit-button {
  display: block;
}

input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 250px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: grey;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #3DBB96;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="leftSide">
    <div class="login-form">
      <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
        <div class="email-input-field">
          <input type="email" name="emailPost" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="password-input-field">
          <input type="password" name="passwordPost" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="splitter"></div>
  <div class="rightSide">


  </div>
</div>
```

---

EDIT :

The way we align stuff inside a flexed container is : `align-self` on the flex items or `aling-items` on the flexed container, Now since flexbox only goes in one direction either vertically or horizontally, we change that using `flex-direction` property, we put one vertically and align the items as we like, then put another one horizontally and align the items as we like.

I tried to make my own example to make it somewhat clean ?

It's better if you would find a course about flexbox, google it or look for it on youtube (which where i learned everything i know)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #1d1f20;
  color: #FFF;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
}

.main>.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: brown;
}

.main>.left>.form-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main>.left>.form-wrapper>form {
  background: #1d1f20;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.main>.left>.form-wrapper>form>input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main>.split {
  width: 5px;
  background: #00ff74;
}

.main>.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: purple;
  display: flex;
}

.main>.right>.welcome {
  flex: 1;
  background: #2d162d;
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main>.right>.welcome>h2 {
  background: #9a7d9a;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="">
        <input type="button" value="Done !" name="">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="welcome">
      <h2>Welcome !</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This was really helpful. I do have a few questions however. 1) What is *after, before used for in this case? 2) I don't understand what grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr; does/is? 3) What does flex: 1 0 0%; do? Thanks! :)

Comment: You can ignore the before and after for this they shouldn't be there, It's my default styling not relevant for this, grid-template-columns property let's you define columns in your grid container each value represents a column, auto means take as much space as the content needs, 1fr means fill the available space. It's better if you'd google these things rather than me giving you poor explanations, cuz I may skip something, and I don't have much space in a comment to explain everything.

Comment: Oh, okay! Will do. Sorry to bother you, last question. How would I center the splitter in the center of the page and the login-form to the left of it directly? And same with the right side.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have helped me out a ton! :) Thank you again! :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I used flex to create what you required. You will have to check the new CSS and HTML(separator and right-side part) to completely understand what I did.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

body {
  background-color: #ced4da;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.wrapper .login-form,
.wrapper .right-side {
  width: 45%;
}

.login-form {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.email-input-field,
.password-input-field,
.submit-button {
  display: block;
}

input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #3DBB96;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}

.separator {
  width: 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Login.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="login-form">
      <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
        <div class="email-input-field">
          <input type="email" name="emailPost" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="password-input-field">
          <input type="password" name="passwordPost" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="right-side">Right side content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into Flexbox or other options. W3 has a couple of ways to setup a two column layout in their howto article: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp

Also checkout the [complete guide to flexbox from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Michael, just post this as comment.